# Laravel login screen is not logging in nor redirecting to the specified $redirectTo

Tags: php, laravel, authentication

I use the standard [laravel 5.4 authentication](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) system but made a change on the login page.

I wanted my login page to be on the index so I manually added the Authentication routes:

```
//I only changed the get route since I only wanna change the action for the view
Route::get('/', [
  'as' => 'login',
  'uses' => 'TestController@index'
]);
Route::post('login', [
  'as' => '',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@login'
]);
```

This works fine. `localhost/` brings me to my page.

Now I use the same page as the page generated by the laravel Auth:

```
<form action="{{route('login')}}" method="POST">
//Standard input fields with the same names etc...
<input type="email" name="email">
<input type="password" name="password">
<input type="submit" name="submit">
<input type="checkbox" name="remember"> //etc..
</form>
```

And I didnt touch the controller at all:

```
    <?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Auth;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Foundation\Auth\AuthenticatesUsers;

class LoginController extends Controller
{
    /*
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    | Login Controller
    |--------------------------------------------------------------------------
    |
    | This controller handles authenticating users for the application and
    | redirecting them to your home screen. The controller uses a trait
    | to conveniently provide its functionality to your applications.
    |
    */

    use AuthenticatesUsers;

    /**
     * Where to redirect users after login.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $redirectTo = 'home';

    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('guest')->except('logout');
    }
}
```

It doesnt matter whether I give in the right or wrong login credentials, it just refreshes the page.

What did I do wrong here? Register etc works perfect. Same form and the paths of the routes:

```
Route::get('register', [
  'as' => 'register',
  'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@showRegistrationForm'
]);
Route::post('register', [
  'as' => '',
  'uses' => 'Auth\RegisterController@register'
]);
```

Did I forget something when changing the login page to the index page or something?

Comment: if you do not set any aliases for your routes, you cloud use a shorthand for example : `Route::post('/register', 'Auth\RegisterController@register');`.

Comment: @AnwarNairi the register part is all automatically created by the command: `php artisan make:auth`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's because you're trying to send the POST request to the same page, since `route('login`)` == your homepage.

Change

```
<form action="{{route('login')}}" method="POST">
```

By

```
<form action="{{url('login')}}" method="POST">
```

### Updated answer

You don't need to always use named routes and it's sometimes easier to just use `url()`.

Do like that:

```
Route::get('/', [
  'as' => 'login',
  'uses' => 'TestController@index'
]);
Route::post('/', 'Auth\LoginController@login');
```

and

```
<form action="{{ url('/') }}" method="POST">
```

Comment: Why doesn't route work? Url works but this `route('login')`part of the code was also automatically genereated by `php artisan make:auth`. I dont understand why route doesnt work

Comment: Your route named `login` is your homepage. So you're trying to send the POST request to your homepage instead of `/login`.

Comment: Okay lets say I want to keep the route as its automatically generated, instead of  `Route::get('/', [
  'as' => 'login',
  'uses' => 'TestController@index'
]);` I'd use: `Route::get('login', [
  'as' => '/',
  'uses' => 'Auth\LoginController@showLoginForm'
]);`

How would I get this login form to show on the index page?

Comment: Thanks you're a lifesaver. I kept the route:post of login the same though. I used `url('login')`. It's fixed\

Comment: But wait there's 1 thing I dont get. Why is my register working then? Isn't it doing the same as my login?

Comment: No, because when you're on your register page, it's `/register`, so if you POST to where you are, it's still `/register`so it's good.